# Shopify App - Is there any webhook available to get "Abandoned carts" information

Tags: shopify, shopify-app

This question is related to developing an app on shopify platform that will send emails to customers for their abandoned checkouts. Gone through Shopify API/forum but couldn't find any useful information on this.

I have some basic question to understand how the whole flow works.

1) Are there any webhooks available that get fired by Shopify when a cart is considered abandoned?

2) Or do I need to manually query the store for carts that are marked abandoned by Shopify? Is there any API for that?

3) Is there a mechanism to figure out if the cart status is still unpaid before triggering the abandoned cart email, just to avoid a scenario where the customer already paid for it?

Answer (score 4):

There is no information about abandoned carts in Shopify. But there is for abandoned checkouts. If the user enters the checkout stage then the order is considered abandoned by default till he completes the checkout process.
So it is not logically possible to have webhook for abandoned checkouts on Shopify platform. You can poll the REST api mentioned by [@David](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52598543/7498888) to get the data from time to time.

Answer (score 3):

The Shopify Documentation is always a great place to check! You can try it next time you have a question about how Shopify works with respect to Apps and API work.

https://help.shopify.com/en/api/reference/orders/abandoned_checkouts